# Return boolean in Cypress

Tags: return, cypress, exists

I have function in another class file (following pageObject):

```
getElementExists(xpathSelector){
        cy.xpath(`count(${xpathSelector})`).then(count => {
            const exist = (count > 0) ? true : false
            console.log(exist)
            return cy.wrap(exist)            
        })  
    }
```

In another js, I try to use function:

```
basePage.getElementExists(XPath).then((fi) => {
       console.log(fi)
})
```

I get      `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

How can I return boolean in Cypress and use it further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xpath library is no longer used, but you can still evaluate `xpathSelector` with [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) which is built into the browser.

```js
getElementExists(xpathSelector) {
  return cy.document().then(document => {
    const result = document.evaluate(`count(${selector})`, document)
    const exists = !!result.numberValue   // 0 yields false, 1+ yields true
    return exists
  })
}
```

```js
basePage.getElementExists(xpathSelector).then(exists => {
  console.log('exists', exists)
})
```

An example test:

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com');

basePage.getElementExists('/html/body//h1')    // h1 heading is on the page
  .should('eq', true)                          // passes

basePage.getElementExists('/html/body//span')  // span is not on the page
  .should('eq', false)                         // passes
```

Answer (score 3):

`cy.xpath()` has been deprecated. The equivalent to  `cy.xpath(count(...))` in Cypress is `its('length')`.

The following works in the latest Cypress versions:

```js
getElementExists(selector) {
  return cy.get(selector).its('length').then(count => {
    const exists = !!(count > 0)
    return cy.wrap(exists)
  })
}
```

In the test:

```js
basePage.getElementExists(path).then((exists) => {
  console.log(exists)
})
```

---

You can use page object models, but a [Cypress custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) is simpler.

In `cypress/support/commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('elementExists', (selector) => {
  cy.get(selector).its('length').then(count => {
    const exists = !!(count > 0)
    cy.wrap(exists)
  })
}
```

In the test:

```js
cy.elementExists(path).then((exists) => {
  console.log(exists)
})
```

Comment: cy.get(selector) is failing if element doesn't exist, so chained functions are not executed

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is undefined because you aren't returning it from the `getElementExists` function. Additionally, because it will be used within a Cypress command chain, it doesn't need to be wrapped when it is returned.

```js
getElementExists(xpathSelector){
        return cy.xpath(`count(${xpathSelector})`).then(count => {
            const exist = (count > 0) ? true : false
            console.log(exist)
            return exist          
        })  
    }
```